# Imported range time values dont match source range time values Google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have simple google spreadsheet with two sheets: sheet1 and sheet2. In sheet2 there are time values in column A which I am trying to copy to column A in sheet2. I wrote a script(please see link) for it but values are not the same. What class/method do I need to use in order to get same values in both sheets.

I noticed if I format column A values in sheet2 to text than I get matching values but problem is I am not allowed to that and that column must remain formatted as time.

Also, my second question(please ignore if its off topic). If I have work schedule in google sheet for 3 employees: John,Peter and Mike and they all have editing permissions. If Mike decides to use filter to filter out just his work schedule, is it possible for other two employees to have unedited sheet(as I believe Mike's actions will affect other two persons). What I mean is, is it possible to restrict one persons actions just to view he is looking at while other have unaffected version(together work schedule in this case)?

link for spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tOtwzM0CxDHBXzC8ECeXlfaTGC4i7rH2XMYYszqRINM/edit?usp=sharing

Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not entirely sure what the problem is, your script is working as intended and you have the same values in sheet1 as in sheet2. The only difference is that in Sheet1 you have a date format and on sheet2 you only indicate the time. I have changed the number format in the sheet1 and as you can see it's the same.

The problem you are having is that by indicating only the time, you let the sheet assume any date. For time it's not that big a deal, but you must be sure that time formats are the same. use `getNumberFormat()` and `setNumberFormat()` ([read here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNumberFormat())) to set the correct formats when copying or have the formatting set in advance

As for filtering — you can simply give them view-only access and let them use filtere views (right under "Filter"). A filter will hide information for everyone on the sheet, while a filter view will only be visible to that person. You can also pre-set filter views for them as those with edit access can save filter views.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It did solved the problem. However, spreadsheet I provided is just a replica of one part of my original spreadsheet. And in original spreadsheet, even before coming here I tried formatting both the source and target range as time but it would still give me 8 hours time discrepancy.

Comment: Apologies,hit enter by mistake. What solved the problem was your setNumberFormat(), as I first set all values in that range to text and that imported it to new sheet.

Comment: Once more, much appreciated!